# С++ Экономичней ли по времени/памяти передача базовых типов по ссылке?

Tags: c++

Допустим, будет ли выигрыш по времени выполнения/памяти во втором случае или нет?

```
 void f(int x)
{
  cout << x;
}
void f(const int &x)
{
  cout << x;
}
```

Если передать объект по значению, то вызовется конструктор копирования, а после выхода из тела функции -- деструктор. Теоретически, это тоже занимает время. А что происходит, когда передается ссылка? И сколько памяти она занимает?
Для какого-нибудь "увесистого" объекта выигрыш по памяти точно будет, это понятно, а вот как лучше поступать с базовыми типами -- вопрос.

Comment: Для типов, помещающихся в регистр, ABI с передачей аргументов в регистрах (типично для 64-bit архитектур), компилятора с хорошей оптимизации и с учетом того, что `f()` внешняя (раздельно компилируемая) функция код с передачей по ссылке скорее всего  будет на 1 команду больше

Comment: Быстрее точно не будет. Либо чуть медленнее, либо так же. Вроде так.

Comment: Если архитектура 64-bit, указатель будет занимать 8 байт, при скромных 4 байтах `int`(чаще всего).

Comment: у Страуструпа есть рекомендация - если тип параметра до трех размеров int (то есть, обычно это 12 байт), то лучше передать по значению. Больше трех - скорее всего лучше по ссылки. https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-in

Comment: У базовых типов нет конструкторов и деструкторов. А даже если и были бы, то они все равно были бы тривиальными, т.е. воображаемыми и никакого времени не отнимающими. Поэтому рассматривать базовые типы с этой точки зрения смысла нет.

Comment: Теоретически сам вывод в консоль займет настолько больше времени, чем передача аргумента (которой из-за оптимизатора скорее всего не будет вообще), что уж этим эффектом точно можно пренебречь...

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически сам вывод в консоль займет настолько больше времени, чем передача аргумента (которой из-за оптимизатора скорее всего не будет вообще), что уж этим эффектом точно можно пренебречь...

Вот смотрите, на VC++ 2017:

```
void f(int x)
{
  cout << x;
}
void g(const int &x)
{
  cout << x;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    f(x);
    g(x);
}
```

И что мы видим?

```
main    PROC                        ; COMDAT

; 18   : {

$LN8:
    sub rsp, 40                 ; 00000028H

; 19   :     int x;
; 20   :     cin >> x;

    lea rdx, QWORD PTR x$[rsp]
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:?cin@std@@3V?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cin
    call    ??5?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@AEAH@Z ; std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator>>

; 10   :   cout << x;

    mov edx, DWORD PTR x$[rsp]
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
    call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@H@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<

; 14   :   cout << x;

    mov edx, DWORD PTR x$[rsp]
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
    call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@H@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<

; 21   :     f(x);
; 22   :     g(x);
; 23   : }

    xor eax, eax
    add rsp, 40                 ; 00000028H
    ret 0
main    ENDP
```

Именно то, что я и говорил: вызова как такового нет, функция заинлайнена, все строго одинаково...

Comment: вопрос не про «заинлайнит или нет»...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я понимаю, что вас очень интересует поведение сферического коня в вакууме... Каждый компилятор будет решать этот вопрос по-своему, как и на разных платформах. Общий ответ я дал, кстати - различиями можно пренебречь.